# Travis setup Postgres From environment variables

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

I've added three (3) environment variables which I'm trying to used to setup the db correctly.

These are the variables:

- DB_NAME
- DB_USER
- DB_PW

In the `before_script` section of `.travis.yml` I would run something like this:

```
before_script:
- psql -c "\set pw `echo "$db_pw"`"
- psql -c "\set user `echo "$db_user"`"
- psql -c "\set name `echo "$db_name"`"
- psql -c "create database :'name'"
- psql -c "CREATE :user WITH PASSWORD ':pw';"
```

However, that doesn't work since the result of `\set` is lost after each command.

How can I setup the db based on what on my environment variables?

Comment: Why don't you add those using Travis CI's UI? BTW, adding these things in your `.travis.yml` file is not a good idea. Also, take a look at `travis encrypt` command to hide these things.

Comment: I did add the environment variables to travis via the UI. Now I am trying to read them out and setup the DB with them

Comment: Oh, got it. Another thing that you can do is to write these commands in one line separated by semi-colon. Actually, there's this "I'm trying..." that's why.

Comment: Are you able to read one environment variable?

Comment: To access an environment variable, you need to use `$` prefix before a variable name e.g. `$DB_NAME`. So, the first line of your script will be **psql -c "\set pw `echo $DB_PW`"**.

Comment: The $ got lost somehow when I copy pasted it. The issue is that postgres '\set' is lost after each command.

Comment: Right. How did you verify it? Is that `create database...` line correct?

Comment: Another thing you can do is to write a script file with these commands and in `before_script` you can run it like `psql -f <filename>`.